# Adobe Analytics visitor ID firing incorrectly on exit link using DTM

Tags: adobe-analytics

I'm using DTM to deploy Adobe Analytics on a very small single page application and are still relatively new to DTM as a company with no one having prior experience. We have custom code set up so that we can clear the variables after the tracking links have been called. We have not set up outbound links. We have set up events to fire a s.tl() call from custom code, not the adobe analytics section, when exit links are clicked. However, for some reason this is sending an fid instead of an AID to our report suite. We've added the visitor ID code in the section of the tool where we placed all the s_code and not in the custom page code area of the s_code if that matters.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Why not add the Visitor ID Service tool in DTM?

This configuration will automatically request the AID and deploy it correctly. With this implementation you won't need to touch the s_code / app measurement file.

Hope this helps.